# Fastroute, htaccess and subfolders on windows

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have this structure:

```
www/subfold
www/subfold/public/index.php
www/subfold/.htaccess
www/subfold/...etcetera
```

I'm using wamp64.
I need to redirect all the requests to public/index.php.

When i had index.php on www/subfold/, this .htaccess worked like a charm.

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfold/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

How can i modify this to work in subfold/public/index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfold/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . public/index.php [L]
```

Note target of `public/index.php` in `RewriteRule`.